# Module not found when attempting to create and use package

Tags: python, package

I am attempting to create a module and use it in another program.

I have tried various changes to **init**.py

Structure -

```
PackageName
    FolderA
        FileA.py
            ClassA
        __init__.py (blank)
    FileB.py
        ClassB
    __init__.py (shown below)
```

**init**.py

```
import PackageName.FolderA
from PackageName.FolderA.FileA import ClassA
from PackageName.FileB import ClassB
```

main file using this package

```
#just imports package does nothing else
import PackageName
```

what changes do I need to make to the init file to be able to access classA when I attempt to use ClassA in the init file, it throws an error `No module named PackageName.FolderA`.

Comment: Do the subfolders have their own `__init__.py` files?

Comment: @JohnGordon no.

Comment: If this is Python 2, they need to.

Comment: It's python 3, and actually, there is a blank `__init__.py` file in the subdirectory, I guess it was auto generated. @JohnGordon

Comment: Please edit the structure to indicate where the `__init__.py` files are and the contents of each.

Comment: @JohnGordon done.

Comment: Is the parent directory of `PackageName` in your `PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: Does not like that, I can do `import PackageName.FolderA` or I can do `from .FolderA import ..` @JohnGordon

Comment: @JohnGordon I am building this into a WHL file and then installing the WHL in a different virtual env.